# ElasticSearch cluster performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I was running a single-node `ElasticSearch` server with 6kk docs indexed.

I was filling a lack of performance, so I decided to scale out.

I configured  4 additional nodes in cloud(4 more instances).

So I have one master node( on which I also store data) and 4 non-master nodes with data.

Also I have switched from 5 shards to 10(so now I have 2 shards per server), because I have now 8kk docs in index and more are coming.

And the performance of queries dropped down at least twice!,

What should I configure/check?

Comment: If you need more performance when searching (querying) rather than when inserting (indexing) data, you should raise the amount of **replicas**, not **shards**.

Comment: I have added replicas(now I have 2 for every shard) - but it didn't help much.

Comment: could you give example of queries you're trying to execute? Something to keep in mind: one you have one node all queries are executed in it, now that you add 4 more nodes, when you execute a query (depending on query and data spread) it's possible that your nodes have to "talk" and exchange information about your query before you get the answer so if there is some latency between them this might cause it to process longer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could perform a test on your primary shards to find optimal shard capacity. There is a point which if you reach your shard might get slower because of the amount of documents it has to handel

Comment: Check your memory maybe you reached a point where you don't have enough RAM's to execute your queries, what is your heap size?

Comment: Thank you, Thezeus, for the advices. I have queries with many filters. The point is that they have changed, but time increased twice at least. I have only 300m of memory, case this are minimal instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the thiing was about to many shards(I was using 10 shards and 2 replicas, moved to 5 shard and 2 replicas) and lack of memory. So I started few servers with more memory and performance improved.